# Adding Node to SelectedNode

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I am new to Treeviews and would like to know why the "New Node" is not added to the SelectedNode.

```
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add("Document")
    Dim ParentNode As New TreeNode("Document")
    TreeView1.SelectedNode = ParentNode
    ParentNode.Nodes.Add("New Node")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a new Document node that isn't the same node as the Document node that was added to the TreeView nodes collection.

Try it this way:

```
Dim docNode As New TreeNode("Document")
TreeView1.Nodes.Add(docNode)
TreeView1.SelectedNode = docNode
docNode.Nodes.Add("New Node")
```